# Plotting an oscillating function on Mathematica

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Hey I'm trying to make a phase space plot of an oscillator's position over a period of cycles and whenever I go to enter in my plot function there is no error returned but I'm presented with a blank graph (in other words just the axes and no points). Have searched alternative ways to approach the problem and nothing seems to help. Here is what I have code wise...

```
\[Alpha] = 0.1; \[Gamma] = 0.05; \[Omega] = 1;

solna = NDSolve[{x''[t] - \[Gamma] (1 - x[t]^2) * x'[t] + 
 x[t] == \[Alpha]*Cos[\[Omega]*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0},x[t], {t, 0, 100*2\[Pi]/\[Omega]}]'
xn[tt_] := Evaluate[x[t] /. solna[[1]]] /. t -> tt
y[tt_] := Evaluate[D[x[t] /. solna, t]][[1]] /. t -> tt
z[tt_] := \[Omega]*tt
ParametricPlot[{xn[tt], y[tt]}, {tt, 0, 20}]
```

Comment: It works if: `solna = NDSolve[{x''[t] - \[Gamma] (1 - x[t]^2)*x'[t] + 
      x[t] == \[Alpha]*Cos[\[Omega]*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, 
   x[t], {t, 0, 100*2 \[Pi]/\[Omega]}];` you use a semicolon to finish off this expression. Also bugs tag cannot be used without proper verification by the community. Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

To make it most concise, and avoid intermediate assignments, I would recommend solving for `x` rather than `x[t]`; you can then just ask for `x'[t] /. solna` and the derivative of the `InterpolatingFunction` will be calculated automatically:

```
α = 0.1; γ = 0.05; ω = 1;
eq = {x''[t] - γ (1 - x[t]^2)*x'[t] + x[t] == α* Cos[ω*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};

solna = NDSolve[eq, x, {t, 0, 100*2 π/ω}];

ParametricPlot[{x[t], x'[t]} /. solna, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: parametric plot of x[t] vs. x'[t]]

Answer (score 2):

Here is your corrected and simplified code:

```
\[Alpha] = 0.1; \[Gamma] = 0.05; \[Omega] = 1;
solna = NDSolve[{x''[t] - \[Gamma] (1 - x[t]^2)*x'[t] + 
       x[t] == \[Alpha]*Cos[\[Omega]*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, 
    x[t], {t, 0, 100*2 \[Pi]/\[Omega]}][[1]];
xn[t_] = x[t] /. solna;
y[t_] = D[x[t] /. solna, t];
ParametricPlot[{xn[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! Must've looked right over it...very confusing language to get the hang of.

Comment: With `pure function` you can formulate it a bit easier. `\[Alpha] = 0.1; \[Gamma] = 0.05; \[Omega] = 1;
xsol = x /. 
   First@NDSolve[{x''[t] - \[Gamma] (1 - x[t]^2)*x'[t] + 
        x[t] == \[Alpha]*Cos[\[Omega]*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, 
     x, {t, 0, 100*2 \[Pi]/\[Omega]}];
ParametricPlot[{xsol[t], xsol'[t]}, {t, 0, 20}] `